# PHP SimpleXMLElement special character encoding / decoding

Tags: php, utf-8

I've got the folowing xml string in php:

```
$str="<name>An☢maly</name>";
```

I then do the following:

```
$tmp=new SimpleXMLElement($str);
```

if I do:

```
echo $tmp->name;
```

I get this:

```
Anâ˜¢maly
```

When I do:

```
echo utf8_decode($tmp->name);
```

I get:

```
An?maly
```

How do I get PHP to display that funny character, it also does it with the following:

```
ƎnƔy™ = ?n?y?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use

```
header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

before output (if you use browser)

P.S: Anâ˜¢maly - this is output when browser render page in "ISO-8859-1" charset instead "UTF-8"

Comment: This was the browser confusing me thanks, the xml document was UTF-8 from the beginning but html was not defined.

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, I'm doing the exact same thing and it is displaying properly in web browser:

```
<?php
$str="<xml><name>ƎnƔy™</name></xml>";
$tmp=new SimpleXMLElement($str);
echo $tmp->name;
?>
```

I noticed that it didn't work properly unless I saved the source file as a UTF8 encoded file. I'm using Programmer's Notepad and clicked file > properties and changed the 'Encoding' parameter to UTF-8 to achieve this.

Also, UTF8 characters will not print correctly on windows command line, which may also be your problem.